# en vez de que se rompa diciendo el error "1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails", mostrar un mensaje al usuario

Tags: php, mysql, mvc

Esta es la situación:

Hay un producto registrado en mi base de datos con los siguientes datos:

INSERT INTO `producto` (`codigo`, `nombre`, `descripcion`, `cantidad`, `precio`, `stock`, `imagen`, `codigoMedida`, `cedulaAdministrador`) VALUES
(1, 'miel', 'rica miel', 1000, 5000, 200, '1.jpg', 2, '27840650');

INSERT INTO `unidades_medida` (`codigo`, `descripcion`, `abreviatura`) VALUES
(1, 'Kilogramos', 'Kg ');
INSERT INTO `unidades_medida` (`codigo`, `descripcion`, `abreviatura`) VALUES
(2, 'gramos', 'gr');

El problema radica que cuando estoy haciendo un proyecto en php y tengo un método para eliminar

```
public function eliminarLlaveExcepciones($llave,$valor) {
        $resultado=null;
        try {
            $query = "DELETE FROM " . static::$tabla . " WHERE $llave = $valor LIMIT 1";
            // debuguear($query);
            $resultado = self::$db->query($query);
            // debuguear($query);

            if ($resultado === false) {
                $errorInfo = self::$db->errorInfo();
                // Verifica si el código de error es '23000' (violación de integridad referencial)
                if ($errorInfo[1] == '23000') {
                    echo "Error: No se puede eliminar la llave primaria porque está siendo referenciada en otro lugar.";
                } else {
                    echo "Error: " . $errorInfo[2]; // Otro tipo de error
                }
            } else {
                // Resto de tu código después de la eliminación exitosa
                echo "Llave primaria eliminada exitosamente";
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // Otras excepciones generales (no relacionadas con la base de datos)
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
        return $resultado;
    }
```

La situación es que yo tengo un crud para unidad de medida, pero cuando voy a eliminar la medida 2 (gramos), la aplicación se rompe mostrando el mensaje:

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Cannot delete or update a
> parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Yo se que el error pasa porque intento eliminar algo que ya esta siendo usado en otro registro, PERO lo que quiero yo es atrapar ese error para mostrarle al usuario desde la pagina un mensaje tipo "no puedes borrar este registro porque esta siendo usado en otro registro" y que dicho mensaje se demore 10 segundos, y vuelva a la página principal del crud de medida, ya que por el momento solo se rompe la aplicación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cómo estás invocando a _eliminarLlaveExcepciones_?

Answer (score 0):

Parece que estás mezclando herramientas. En PHP existen básicamente dos controladores para interactuar con la base de datos. Por un lado `PDO` y por otro lado `mysqli`.

El método `errorInfo()` que usas en tu respuesta es propio de PDO, pero el mensaje de error en la captura de pantalla que muestras es un `mysqli_sql_exception`, que es propio de `mysqli`.

En cualquier caso, tú puedes manejar todos los errores desde el bloque `catch`. Aquí crearemos un array asociativo llamado `$customErrors` . Este array tendrá como clave el número de error y como valor el mensaje que quieras personalizar ([ver aquí todas los números de error](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-errors/8.0/en/server-error-reference.html)).

Con esta forma de programar, la parte del `try` queda limpia, pues en ella sólo deberías manejar los casos de éxito.

Veamos la forma de resolverlo, según uses `mysqli` o `PDO`.

### `mysqli`

```
public function eliminarLlaveExcepciones($llave,$valor) {
    $resultado=null;
    $customErrors=[
        23000=>"No se puede eliminar la llave primaria porque está siendo referenciada en otro lugar.",
        1453=>"Ha ocurrido un fallo de llave foránea",
    ];
    try {
        $query = "DELETE FROM " . static::$tabla . " WHERE $llave = $valor LIMIT 1";
        self::$db->query($query);
        echo "Llave primaria eliminada exitosamente";
    } catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
        //Si el código está en $customErrors se mostrará el mensaje personalizado
        echo $customErrors[$e->getCode()] ?? "Ha ocurrido otro error del tipo PDOException";
    }
    return $resultado;
}
```

### `PDO`

Si usas PDO, en el `catch` podemos verificar si la instancia del error es del tipo `PDOException`, para obtener el código y personalizar el mensaje en caso de que dicho código esté en nuestro array.

El método quedaría así:

```
public function eliminarLlaveExcepciones($llave,$valor) {
    $resultado=null;
    $customErrors=[
        23000=>"No se puede eliminar la llave primaria porque está siendo referenciada en otro lugar.",
        1453=>"Ha ocurrido un fallo de llave foránea",
    ];
    try {
        $query = "DELETE FROM " . static::$tabla . " WHERE $llave = $valor LIMIT 1";
        self::$db->query($query);
        echo "Llave primaria eliminada exitosamente";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        if($e instanceof PDOException) {
            //Si el código está en $customErrors se mostrará el mensaje personalizado
            echo $customErrors[$e->getCode()] ?? "Ha ocurrido otro error del tipo PDOException";
        } else {
            // Otras excepciones generales (no relacionadas con la base de datos)
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    return $resultado;
}
```

Cabe decir que, antes de PHP 8, para que el manejo de excepciones funcione en PDO debes encenderlo, cuando creas la conexión preferiblemente, pasando en las opciones `[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]` o bien seteándolo como atributo: `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`. Desde PHP 8 esto viene por defecto en PDO y no hay que activarlo ([ver el Manual de PHP para más detalles](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.error-handling.php)).

### Otras recomendaciones

Por otra parte, si vas a usar esta técnica en varios métodos, debes sacar a `$customErrors` de aquí, y trasladarlo a una clase ayudadora o construir tu propio manejo de errores, donde incluyas tus mensajes personalizados. Esta es una buena práctica. De hecho, ningún programa se puede considerar acabado mientras no incorpore un manejo de errores robusto y personalizado, en el que se eviten mostrar al usuario mensajes de error internos.

Finalmente, tu código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *inyección SQL*. Deberías usar **consultas preparadas** para neutralizar ese grave agujero de seguridad.